# How can I calculate the range from 0 to 1 with 52 numbers in between?

Tags: python, numpy, increment

I am trying to print out a list that calculates 52 numbers between 0 to 1 (so a lot of float numbers are expected in the output).

However, when I tried doing this in Python, it's printing out 0:

```
for i in range(0,1,52):
     print(i)
```

Apologies, I am an absolute beginner and trying to learn!

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there a function in numpy that could solve this

Comment: `np.linspace`??

Comment: You seem to be confused about the arguments to the range function and what it outputs. I recommend a very basic python tutorial rather than stack overflow.